# How to retrieve target menu of specific list web part for CAMOpt?

Tags: 2013, web-part, javascript

I'm adding a custom action on the context menu of the item using javascript CAMOpt function:

```
function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx)
{
CAMOpt(m,'View (new window)','javascript:window.open(\'DispForm.aspx?ID=' + currentItemID + '\');','/_layouts/images/LIST.GIF');
return false;
}
```

In the case I have a web page with different web parts, the code above updates the context menu for all web parts.

How I can apply the CAMOpt on a specific target menu of a specific web part only?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can loop through all the web parts on the current page and inside if condition compare the id of the webpart to your webpart's id?

Comment: thanks @uberz91 for your suggestion. It was not really the correct solution, but  it gave me some "beta" to find the final answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Custom_AddListMenuItems injection point is called anytime the context menu is invoked on click event.

To apply a different menu on all web parts connected to the a specific list  only, just make a check on the ctx list name as follows:

```
function Custom_AddListMenuItems(m, ctx)
{
    if(ctx.listName == "{0738B7FB-4C2E-4595-8CB3-0F9C039E281C}")
    {
        CAMOpt(m, ...);
        return false;
    }
}
```

To apply a specific context menu on the specific list web part only, you can check on the web part id:

```
if(ctx.clvp.wpid == "c4e47721-5325-4f06-9ce4-2076e87c9d51")
{
    // CAMOpt here
    return false;
}
```