# Hyperlink for Workflow

Tags: calculated-column, url, hyperlink

I've made one calculated field and in there Hyperlink for workflow.

```
=("<a href='https://Site/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Workflows/JustDoIt/JustDoIt.aspx?List={b5cf27e0-a4f1-4e2a-82e8-1b598ef4af3b}&ID=44&ItemGuid={E7F36A55-D6BB-4034-BE51-E58644AF09CB}&TemplateID={03aef3fc-f98b-42b5-9585-06e52da3736c}&Source=https://site/test-anto/Lohnabrechnung/Forms/AllItems.aspx?'><img src='https://site/test-anto/SiteAssets/eye-icon.png' style='height:20px; width:20px;'/> </a>")
```

But it is going on Start form. So i need to start button. How can I do without clicking on Start button.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are merely creating a URL to the initiation form of the workflow which users have to start. If you want to provide the users the ability to initiate the workflow from the view itself without going to the initiation page, you'd want to do something like this:
http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=StartWorkflow&referringTitle=Workflow

I've used this in the past but don't have an examples any more.

Answer (score 0):

A very extensive answer on getting a Workflow to start from a VIEW with a Calculated Column was posted just over a month ago

[Can I add a start workflow link to a column in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view/150796#150796)