# How to Create reminder on SharePoint 2010 Calendar "without workflow"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar, reminder

I already made up a reminder, based on calculate column and  workflow, but I think this is not the strategical way!!Loading workflows for thousands of members caused my server get heavy.
so, I am looking for a rational and logic solution to solve the reminder problem same as out look.(the Alert didn't solve problem for exact time)
if any one has any idea I would appreciate a lot!
Thanks
Sh.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2010 it is the usual solution if you want a no .Net coding solution.

So there is your answer, **if** you run into perfomance problem; go .Net

For completeness:

In SP2013 you can access the Workflow Services from the Client and defer a whole lot of logic to Views:

[Obtain workflow ID by title using CSOM?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160490/obtain-workflow-id-by-title-using-csom/160492#160492)

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but as you mentioned it will work in SP 2013, even if you have any Js idea for an alert message I would appreciate., I mean a conditional popup, for example if "Today" Eq "Remind Date" which is a calculate column with formula.   Regards Shadi

Comment: For solutions in a **View** see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336

Comment: Hi, despite it is not like popup reminder but it is great!! Thanks, I don't know about java but I became interested to learn!

Comment: It is "JavaScript" (or JS or JScript). Java is a totally different programming language. WIth JavaScript you can create pop-ups as well, only restriction is one has to open a View. As where Workflows or Alerts are automatic.