# Start SP2013 workflow with one onlick using java scripts

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, javascript, custom

I need some help adding a modal dialog box to a java-scripts.

I found this java-scripts code that can be use to start a SP2013 workflow using a calculated column which is working fine. however, i think it will work better on my project if i can add a (YES/NO) modal dialog box to the code.

[Can I add a start workflow link to a column in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view)

Ideally, i should like to present the users with a prompt/dialog box with choices yes/No where YES will start the workflow and NO will just close the dialog box without starting the workflow.

here is the Script:

`="<button style=""cursor:pointer;"" onclick=""{"
&"event.preventDefault();"
&"function startWorkflow(itemID, wfName) {"
&"  function __startWorkflow() {"
&"      var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),"
&"          wfsManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx,ctx.get_web()),"
&"          wfSubs = wfsManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().enumerateSubscriptionsByList(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);"
&"      ctx.load(wfSubs);"
&"      ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {"
&"          wfsEnum = wfSubs.getEnumerator();"
&"          while (wfsEnum.moveNext()) {"
&"              var wfSub = wfsEnum.get_current();"
&"              if (wfSub.get_name() === wfName) {"
&"     wfsManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(wfSub,itemID,new Object());"
&"                  SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Init Workflow: '+wfName+' on item: '+itemID, false);"
&"              }}});}"
&"  if (!SP.WorkflowServices) {"
&"      var script = document.createElement('script');"
&"      script.src = '/_layouts/15/sp.workflowservices.js';"
&"      script.onload = __startWorkflow;"
&"      document.head.appendChild(script);"
&"  } else {__startWorkflow();}"
&"}"
&"var TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"

&"startWorkflow(TR.id.split(',')[1] , 'YOUR_WORKFLOW_TITLE_GOES_HERE');"
&"}"">Collect Signature</button>"`

Comment: If the answer was helpful could you remove it from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 0):

It is all JavaScript between those &"" quotes

So with Notepad, you **very carefully** have to add:

```
 [existingcode]

 &"if(confirm('You realy want to start this Workflow?'){"

 [existingcode]

 &"}"

 [existingcode]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Danny.
I tried your suggestion multiple times but it does not work. maybe i'm not placing the if confirm condition in the right place.

if you take a look at your old post Update #1. you add something like `&"alert(url);"
&"SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog',{url:url});"`

is it possible to use something like &"SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog',{url:url});" instead of `SP.UI.Notify.addNotification('Init Workflow: '+wfName+' on item: '+itemID, false);"`

Comment: It is a real pain to check, but it is just JavaScript, each line wrapped in a ``&"  "`` So you can create a normal JS file, execute it, make it work, then all you have to do is carefully make it a SharePoint string again.

Comment: Here is a bare JS script answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160490/obtain-workflow-id-by-title-using-csom/160492#160492