# Troubleshots when starting workflow from a button in a calculated column

Tags: 2013, workflow, calculated-column

In the following post is described how to start a workflow from a button defined in a calculated column:
[Can I add a start workflow link to a column in a list view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view/179192?s=1|1.9464#179192)

Very good! But I experience the following problem:

> the workflow only launches only if you double-click the button. A
>   single click displays the Notification but does not start the
>   workflow.

Is there anybody who got the same issue? Any solution?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 2):

Does the double-click issue still happen if you're using the JSLink approach as opposed to the calculated field approach?

It should be easy to try the JS Link approach and test.

Per Microsoft's announcement yesterday it sounds like the calculated field solution (creating a button with a link) won't work going forward.

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields
- http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2017/js-link-no-more-html-in-calculated-field-change/

Comment: Hi, i did not try it yet.. Do you have a good post where this approach is described? Thanks!