# Sharepoint 2013 Button in List View to Start an SP 2010 Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, calculated-column

I was wondering if someone could help me to get this feature in SharePoint list view. I want to get a button in Custom List View itself with a Calculated Column to start an 2010 SP Workflow.

I already checked [this topic here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150787/can-i-add-a-start-workflow-link-to-a-column-in-a-list-view), but couldn't find the solution for my case. The link for Workflow association looks a little bit different in my case:

```
http://mycompany/sites/mysite/_layouts/15/IniWrkflIP.aspx?List={bfd9ac18-3922-422e-bbb7-f0f6d9d81755}&ID=173&ItemGuid={E49BF8B5-05F3-4E2C-A67C-ACD4153ED87B}&TemplateID={d8c29b55-0640-4815-9084-5ae16a0ad0f4}&Source
```

Here we have ID and `ItemGuid` as dynamic.

Was wondering if there is someone who could help me - I really need this kind of solution for my project.

Comment: have you tried to create custom action in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Yes, but what I realy need is a button in list view. Thank you